# Docker compose volumes not mounted on windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm running Windows containers with Docker for Windows. I used Visual Studio container orchestration to generate the docker-compose and currently my docker-compose.override.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  test:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44308
    ports:
      - "50132:80"
      - "44308:443"
    volumes:
      - C:\directory:C:\directory:ro
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get the directory mounted to the container when starting the docker debug profile. I've tried forward and back slashes, relative paths, other directories, etc. Infuriatingly if I run the container as follows:

```
docker run -it -v C:\directory:C:\directory test cmd
```

the directory is mounted correctly.

I can watch Visual Studio's output of `docker-compose up` and see it mounting the remote_debugger and .nuget and some other stuff, and it shows that `C:\directory` is mounting as well. If I attach to the container, all the automatically mounted volumes are there, but not mine.

I have also tried the extended format for volumes as follows:

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: C:\directory
    target: C:\directory
```

No luck there either.

So what am I doing wrong? I feel like Visual Studio may be the culprit somehow, as the only volumes being mounted are what VS does magically behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Code below works for me with no issues. Check if it works for you

```
services:
  test:
    image: microsoft/windowsservercore:1803
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: d:\test
        target: c:\directory
    command: ["cmd", "/c", "dir", "c:\\directory"]
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Gregory. I've done a little more delving and it turns out VS is generating a docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml which never contains my specified volumes. I guess the bigger issue here is that VS is ignoring my docker-compose (hence why i can run docker-compose up from the command line and the image has the correct volumes).

Comment: I never ever use VS  for anything docker related. It hides so much stuff and does so much it's own thing that it's not worth trying to investigate.